Counting pass/fail within a date range
I have an audit sheet with a couple thousand lines of assets. I would like to count (PASS) status or (FAIL) in column (H) within a date range in column (G). We have to to monthly reports and I want this to auto populate rather than doing filters and doing figures.
=COUNTIFS(H2:H2000,">=11/1/2023",H2:H2000,"<=11/30/2023")*(V4)

Cell V4 just says PASS. I'm trying to count the number of PASS within the designated month.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In V4, try with =COUNTIFS($G$2:$G$2000,">=11/1/2023",$G$2:$G$2000,"<=11/30/2023", $H$2:$H$2000, "PASS")

Mayukh, this is exactly what I needed. Thankyou!!
